# PostgresSQL: Copy table from schemaA to schemaB in the same DB

Tags: postgresql

I have the following scenario, I have a schema called A and a schema called B. Both are in the same DB, both contain the same table, only in schema B it has no content, since I truncated the table with the `TRUNCATE` statement.

I have tried to use the `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` application with the following command.

```
pg_dump --file "table.sql" --username "user" --no-password --verbose --format=p --data-only --table "schemaA.tablename" "db"
```

Get a SQL script with the following statement:

```
COPY schemaA.tablename (column1, column2...) FROM STDIN;

//data
```

I have tried changing that

I have tried changing that `COPY` to `schemaB` but to no avail, the `FROM STDIN` statement I assume is why `pg_restore` takes the data through a file and there is the `STDIN` entry, couldn't I do it this way? Since making the changes does not work.

If this is not possible, the only thing I can think of is to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO schemaB.tablename
SELECT * FROM schemaA.tablename;
```

There is a lot of data, I don't know to what extent it is advisable to do so, what would be the best step to follow?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restore a `pg_dump` to a different schema.

Your `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` solution is good. An alternative could be to use `COPY ... TO` to write the contents of the first table to a file and `COPY ... FROM` to load it into the other table.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts.